# ¿Como marcar checkbox de una tabla ya generada dinamicamente apartir de un JSON, jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

De esta forma genero la lista dinamicamente:

```
var cupones_bienvenida = $('.cupones_bienvenida');
                        var tipoCupon ='';

                        $.each(response.data, function (i) {
                            if (response.data[i].Sub_Tipo == 1){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 1";
                            }
                            else if(response.data[i].Sub_Tipo == 2){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 2";
                            }
                            else{
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 3";
                            }


                              $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td td-cuponera-costarica')
                                        .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content').text(response.data[i].Nombre)))
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text(tipoCupon))
                                        .append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text("Descuento: "+response.data[i].Descuento)))
                                    .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="descuento_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Descuento + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="tipo_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Tipo_cupon + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="sub_tipo" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Sub_Tipo + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="vencimiento" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Fecha_vence + '</div>')

                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
                                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                    .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida);
                                 if (cantidad_llaves === 0) {
                                    $('.cupon_check').prop('disabled', true)
                                }
                            });
                        llenarValores();
```

Cada registro tiene su checkbox.
Al momento de cambiarme de vista guardo un JSON con la informacion de esa lista, principalmente me interesan los checkbox.
La propiedad `chequeado` me devuelve si fue chequeado o no.

```
{
  "titulo": "Cupones oricash",
  "cupones": [
    {
      "identificador": "P20170713786C1",
      "descuento": "100",
      "chequeado": true
    },
    {
      "identificador": "P20170713786C2",
      "descuento": "150",
      "chequeado": false
    },
    {
      "identificador": "P20170813943C1",
      "descuento": "100",
      "chequeado": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Al momento de regresar a la vista, nuevamente se genera la lista dinamicamente, pero esta vez segun el JSON que tenia, debo indicar los checkbox que fueron marcados, lo estoy intentando con esta funcion:

```
function llenarValores(){
        var item_chequeado
        if (json_cupones_chequeados){
            var json_parse = JSON.parse(json_cupones_chequeados);
            $.each(json_parse.cupones, function(i, item) {
               console.log(item);
               item_chequeado = item.chequeado; //Obtengo true o false
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log("Aun no se ha enviado el json");
        }

        $('.cupones_bienvenida > tr').each(function(index, value)
        {
            var cupones = $(this).closest('.cupones');
            //Aca estoy intentando asignar item_chequeado(true o false),para que me indique que checkbox marcados.
            cupones.find('.cupon_check').attr('checked',item_chequeado);

        });
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intentalo asi:

```
function llenarValores(){
    var item_chequeado = [];
    if (json_cupones_chequeados){
        var json_parse = JSON.parse(json_cupones_chequeados);
        $.each(json_parse.cupones, function(i, item) {
           console.log(item);
           item_chequeado.push(item.chequeado); //Obtengo true o false
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("Aun no se ha enviado el json");
    }

    $('.cupones_bienvenida > tr').each(function(index, value)
    {
        var cupones = $(this).closest('.cupones');            
        cupones.find('.cupon_check').attr('checked',item_chequeado[index]);

    });
}
```

Comment: Eso me funciono muy bien !, por favor solo podrías explicarme, perdón.

Comment: En lugar de una variable simple, necesitas un array para guardar los valores.  Declaras el array asi: `var item_chequeado = [];`.  Luego guardas los valores en el array asi: `item_chequeado.push(item.chequeado);`.  Finalmente, para setear los valores, utilizas el indice de la tr que esta guardado en la variable `index` asi: `cupones.find('.cupon_check').attr('checked',item_chequeado[index]);`

Comment: Ah de acuerdo, y perdon como puedo mantener la suma de esos checkbox que fueron selecionados.

Comment: Solo agrega una variable `total` y un `if(item.chequeado)`